# calling javascript function in jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i need to call a javascript function into jquery and the function is from another file .. i don't know how to do it :/ 
this is in the jquery file

```
if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' }  );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
    count ++;
    //i want to add the function here
}
```

here's the js.js file

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function fun() {
        document.write("it's working");
    }
</script>
```

anyone have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: If need to include both files (using script tags or jQuery getScript) and then just call the function `fun()` in second file.

Comment: external .js files should **NOT** have `<script>` tags. it should be just the bare js code. and you load those files via `<script src="file.js"></script>`

Comment: You should not have script tags in js file script tags go to html file if you wan to include the file or create inline script like your second snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include js.js first then your jQuery code. I will suggest make sure that while executing jQuery code your other file should be loaded.

As you are defining `fun()` function globally you can call it directly.

```
if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
  ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
  ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
  $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
  ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' }  );
  ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
  correctCards++;
  count ++;
  fun();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no difference from normal function call. Just put `fun()` in jQuery and include the scripts in the same html file where the js file comes first